# An Android Virtual Device is failed to load

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

[image]

See above picture.

I am not able to create a virtual device in Eclipse; also I face many other issues.

[image]

> This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in.

This question is not similar to others, I've tried many ways to fix it but I can't solve.

Comment: try updating all the components

Comment: i am already update all the components but still problem as it is

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need to update your ADT to a version matching your emulators.

However - ADT is part of the Eclipse IDE suite, which is no longer supported by Google for Android development. The new official suite is [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Therefore I can't tell if there even exists a matching ADT plugin suiting your needs. I suggest migrating Android Studio.

If you do insist on staying with Eclipse, you might be able to circumvent the problem by using 3rd party emulators, which do not depend on the Google stack. Pesonally I use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).